# how to check if the data from server is a serialized array or just a simple string?

Tags: java

I need to serialize

```
ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
```

on server and then send this array to client.

I serialize it and write to `socket.getOutputStream()`:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try{
      ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
      oos.writeObject(arr);
      oos.close();
      socket.getOutputStream().write(bos.toByteArray());
  }catch(IOException exc)
  {
      System.out.println("Series erro!");
  }
```

Client receives bytes from server

```
        byte[] buf=new byte[1024*100];
        //данные приходные
        int r=s.getInputStream().read(buf);
```

And how to check if it is my ArrayList and then deserialize or just a String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to check. You wrote a serialized object: it's a serialized object. Read it with `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`.

You can check what *type* of serialized object with `instanceof`.

And you don't need the ByteArrayOutputStream there. Just construct `new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())` and do the `writeObject()` directly. You're just wasting time and space and money this way.

Comment: I am not only send serialized arrays. I send Strings too - different messages to clients.

Comment: @Артём Царионов Write them all with `writeObject()` and you can read them all with `readObject()`, and then test them with `instanceof`. Just don't mix the APIs if you can't tell what's coming next.